# print ggplot in a loop using chaining command

Tags: r, ggplot2, piping

I am trying to make a set of ggplots in a loop and display them.  I am trying use the `%>%` operator. Here is the toy example which plots points from 1 to 10, each with a different title.

```
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)

data1 <- data.frame('x' = 1:10, 'y' = 1:10)

for (index in 1:10){

  data1 %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    geom_point() +
    ggtitle(paste("plot ",as.character(index)))
}
```

Now, the following code works and produces 10 plots, each with a different title

```
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)

data1 <- data.frame('x' = 1:10, 'y' = 1:10)

for (index in 1:10){


    print(ggplot(data = data1, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    geom_point() +
    ggtitle(paste("plot ",as.character(index))))
}
```

but, I want to use the `%>%` operator to produce a series of plots. I have tried `%>% print()` at the end of title, it runs but does not produce plots for display. Whereas

```
for (index in 1:10){

  data1 %>% 
    print(data = .,ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    geom_point() +
    ggtitle(paste("plot ",as.character(index))))

}
```

produces an error

```
Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class uneval
```

Is there something silly, that I am missing?

Thanks!

Comment: I haven't tried it but wouldn't just piping to the print command work?  `{all your junk} %>% print(.)`

Comment: This runs, but does not display anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's really a matter of order of operations between `%>%` and `+`. You can either block your `ggplot` stuff together like

```
for (index in 1:10){
  data1 %>% {
    ggplot(., aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    geom_point() +
    ggtitle(paste("plot ",as.character(index)))
  } %>% print
}
```

or you can put the entire chain in the print

```
for (index in 1:10) {
  print(data1 %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    geom_point() +
    ggtitle(paste("plot ",as.character(index)))
  )
}
```

Comment: both these approaches produce the plots. Thanks. I like the first one better, even though I don't like to use `.`

Comment: You can't run from `.` using the pipe operator, some times the automatic parameter assigning won't be able to "guess" what you want, or you might need to refer to the data more than once.